# what is the location of mrjob.conf file?

Tags: python, hadoop, virtual-machine, mrjob

My mrjob with hadoop streaming fails. I have a hadoop sandbox on oracle vm with python module mrjob.
Need to make some changes in mrjob.conf as suggested in [Hadoop Error: Error launching job , bad input path : File does not exist.Streaming Command Failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42477386/hadoop-error-error-launching-job-bad-input-path-file-does-not-exist-streami)
But I can't locate this conf file.

Can any one guide me through this?

And btw, the stacktrace of my actual issue is:

```
hduser@ubuntu:~$ python suncode/RatingsBreakdown.py -r hadoop --hadoop-streaming-jar /usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/tools/lib/hadoop-streaming-2.7.2.jar sundata/u.data

Using configs in /etc/mrjob.conf
Looking for hadoop binary in /usr/local/hadoop/bin...
Found hadoop binary: /usr/local/hadoop/bin/hadoop
Using Hadoop version 2.7.2
Creating temp directory /tmp/RatingsBreakdown.hduser.20170921.083051.964674
Copying local files to hdfs:///user/hduser/tmp/mrjob/RatingsBreakdown.hduser.20170921.083051.964674/files/...
Running step 1 of 1...
  session.id is deprecated. Instead, use dfs.metrics.session-id
  Initializing JVM Metrics with processName=JobTracker, sessionId=
  Cannot initialize JVM Metrics with processName=JobTracker, sessionId= - already initialized
  Cleaning up the staging area file:/app/hadoop/data/mapred/staging/hduser577870072/.staging/job_local577870072_0001
  Error launching job , bad input path : File does not exist: /app/hadoop/data/mapred/staging/hduser577870072/.staging/job_local577870072_0001/files/RatingsBreakdown.py#RatingsBreakdown.py
  Streaming Command Failed!
Attempting to fetch counters from logs...
Can't fetch history log; missing job ID
No counters found
Scanning logs for probable cause of failure...
Can't fetch history log; missing job ID
Can't fetch task logs; missing application ID
Step 1 of 1 failed: Command '['/usr/local/hadoop/bin/hadoop', 'jar', '/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/tools/lib/hadoop-streaming-2.7.2.jar', '-files', 'hdfs:///user/hduser/tmp/mrjob/RatingsBreakdown.hduser.20170921.083051.964674/files/RatingsBreakdown.py#RatingsBreakdown.py,hdfs:///user/hduser/tmp/mrjob/RatingsBreakdown.hduser.20170921.083051.964674/files/mrjob.zip#mrjob.zip,hdfs:///user/hduser/tmp/mrjob/RatingsBreakdown.hduser.20170921.083051.964674/files/setup-wrapper.sh#setup-wrapper.sh', '-input', 'hdfs:///user/hduser/tmp/mrjob/RatingsBreakdown.hduser.20170921.083051.964674/files/u.data', '-output', 'hdfs:///user/hduser/tmp/mrjob/RatingsBreakdown.hduser.20170921.083051.964674/output', '-mapper', 'sh -ex setup-wrapper.sh python3 RatingsBreakdown.py --step-num=0 --mapper', '-reducer', 'sh -ex setup-wrapper.sh python3 RatingsBreakdown.py --step-num=0 --reducer']' returned non-zero exit status 512
```

Answer (score 0):

You should look for mrjob.conf in these locations:

The location specified by MRJOB_CONF.

```
~/.mrjob.conf
/etc/mrjob.conf
```

Comment: When I do a echo $MRJOB_CONF it prints nothing. No idea what is going wrong over here.

Comment: Can you try this: mrjob.conf.find_mrjob_conf() if it can't find returns none

Answer (score 0):

You can find file with this command,  `sudo find / -name "mrjob.conf"`.

Usually mrjob.conf is in these locations:

- The location specified by MRJOB_CONF
- ~/.mrjob.conf
- /etc/mrjob.conf

Comment: I guess there is no mrjob.conf in my vm. I have already tried this and locate command too. Although I can see mrjob in list of installed modules in python. Do I need to add one mrjob.conf on my own somewhere then?

Comment: Yeah, if it not exist, you can cerate one.

Comment: created one in etc location. but that does not solve my issue.

Comment: You need to specify the configuration file with the --conf-path flag